# sql Function not returning value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Wrote a function for accepting a Number and a user id and returning a table having individual digit in a single row with that User id. Function created successfully but when i tried to execute function its returning a blank table.
Attaching screenshot of function and output.

[image]

```
Create Function ExtractingDigits(@InputNumber INT, @UserId varchar)
    RETURNS @ReturnTable Table(UserId Varchar(20),  ModNumber Int)
as
begin
Declare @ModNumber Int
While @InputNumber!=0
begin
set @ModNumber= @InputNumber%10
set @InputNumber=@InputNumber/10
insert into @ReturnTable(UserId, ModNumber)
select * from @ReturnTable
end
return
end

select * from ExtractingDigits(123, 'as')
```

Comment: Please add code as formatted text, not as (link to) image.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You are never inserting anything into the table variable you're returning. What is supposed to happen?

Comment: Thankyou so much @Damien_The_Unbeliever i was trying to format code

Comment: You are also calling the procedure with int and varchar, rather than the other way around. What is `as`, is it the `UserId`? Again, what is this function supposed to do?

Comment: Function is for extracting individual digit from a number. As i passed 123 and user id 'as' so this function must return a table having 3 rows with like 'as' 1, 'as' 2 and 'as' 3 @HoneyBadger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to use a `VALUES` clause for your `INSERT` rather than a `SELECT` from an empty table:

```
alter Function ExtractingDigits(@InputNumber INT, @UserId varchar)
    RETURNS @ReturnTable Table(UserId Varchar(20),  ModNumber Int)
as
begin
Declare @ModNumber Int
While @InputNumber!=0
begin
set @ModNumber= @InputNumber%10
set @InputNumber=@InputNumber/10
insert into @ReturnTable(UserId, ModNumber)
values (@UserId,@ModNumber)
end
return
end
go
select * from ExtractingDigits(123, 'as')
```

Just as style comments though, I'd also recommend a) changing either the parameter order or the table definition so that they're both consistent (i.e. have both be `int, varchar` or `varchar, int` rather than swapping) but b) recommend not including `@UserId` in this function at all. This would make the function much more *generically* usable:

```
alter Function ExtractingDigits(@InputNumber INT)
    RETURNS @ReturnTable Table(ModNumber Int)
as
begin
Declare @ModNumber Int
While @InputNumber!=0
begin
set @ModNumber= @InputNumber%10
set @InputNumber=@InputNumber/10
insert into @ReturnTable(ModNumber)
values (@ModNumber)
end
return
end
go
select * from ExtractingDigits(123) cross apply (select 'as' as UserId)
```

Comment: VALUES worked for me but getting only first letter of userid here which is 'A' and digits getting in reverse order 3,2,1 instead of 1,2,3(which won't be a big issue for me) @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @akshaysahu - `varchar` without length (in the parameter definition) defaults to a length of 1. Tables have no inherent order, so `1,2,3` and `3,2,1` are both perfectly valid return values from this function (as would e.g. `2,1,3`)

Comment: Done...Thankyou so much for understanding my problem and giving me quickest solution and ofcourse for formatting my question. Many thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever